# Null in IEnumerable vs IList

Tags: c#, .net, generics, list-comparison

Why can an IEnumerable = null be passed without error but an IList=Null will not compile?

Answer (score 1):

That's not true.  You can set a variable of type IEnumerable or IList to a null reference and it will compile.

There is something else in your code that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
IList<int> Foo() {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you mean. You say a null reference for an IEnumerable can be 'passed without error'. 'Passing' is a runtime thing, but you say with an IList you get a compile error? That sounds confused. You'll need to give us some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with your exact question, it could be because C# is case-sensitive - `null` is a literal, but `Null` isn't. It's hard to say given that you haven't posted any code which could actually compile though.

If that's not the problem in your *real* code, post your real code and we'll see what we can do.